# How to use the power of uvicorn and asgi in django?

Tags: django, gunicorn, wsgi, uvicorn, asgi

I implemented a tiny Django app (v4.0.4) containing a REST API — GET method for retrieving some data. Next, I wanted to run the project using *gunicorn+uvicorn* since I saw a more benchmark performance than a normal deployment in an article. So I decided to get my own benchmark using [`wrk`](https://github.com/wg/wrk) tool.

Here's what I've got:

| Command | Webserver | Protocol | Result (Req/Sec) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` | Django Default | wsgi | `13.06` |
| `gunicorn bitpin.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 2` | gunicorn | wsgi | `45.20` |
| `gunicorn bitpin.asgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 2 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker` | uvicorn+gunicorn | asgi | `22.17` |

However, the above result demonstrates something else!
Is the reason that when I want to use `asgi` I have to use `async` method instead for my API view? If so how can I change a Django REST API view to an `async` one?
Or might I've missed some configurations?

---

[**NOTE**]:

- I ran the benchmark using the following command:

  ```
  wrk -t4 -c11 -d20s -H "Authorization: Token xxx" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/content/
  ```
- It is worth mentioning that for this test I used two workers for `gunicorn` and it is obvious that the higher workers, the better the performance will be.

Comment: If you are running this in a kubernetes environment as a microservice with HPA (horizontal auto scaling) enabled, then you are good with the django default server. kubernetes will keep autoscaling (up or down) depending on the load, it will add or reduce pods (like more uvicorn workers), This will be dynamic. A gunicorn/uvicorn worker numbers are fixed at startup and can't be changed on the fly.

You are most probably talking about a physical server but I thought I will leave my answer here anyway for k8s environments if someone else faces this dilemma.

Answer (score 2):

İf you want create async rest api use one async main function and you can call another synchronous function from this function.

for example:
#`url.py:`

```
path('Create',views.data_export,name='export_database')
```

#`view.py`

```
async def data_export(request):
  if(request.method == 'POST'):
    if(db_connect):
      system_id=request.POST.get('system_id')
      export_id =request.POST.get('export_id')  
      asyncio.create_task(start(system_id,export_id))

  return HttpResponse("Starting")

async def start(system_id,export_id):
  export_task = sync_to_async(start_export,thread_sensitive=False)
  system_id=str(config['COLLECTION_NAME']+'_'+system_id)
  await export_task(system_id,export_id)
```

export_task is a synchronous function.

This is how I made the rest api asynchronous.